# Styling a Button with CSS - problems with the border

Tags: html, css, adobe-brackets

I have a button styled the following way:

```
button, .button {
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 0;
}
```

When I open it in Brackets Live Preview, all buttons have a grayish border. When I open this directly in Firefox, the buttons have no borders. I want the border to appear.

Why?

Manually specifying `border: solid 1px` causes the bottom border to disappear when hovering over the button, which looks ugly.

/edit: yes, I have a hover selector:

```
a {
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease, border-bottom 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease, border-bottom 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease, border-bottom 0.2s ease;
    transition: color 0.2s ease, border-bottom 0.2s ease;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px;
    color: inherit;
}

    a:hover {
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
    }
```

The `a` selector is the right one, since the buttons are defined in the following way:

```
<a href="foo.html" class="button">bar</a>
```

Comment: Do you have any styles with `hover` selector?

Comment: Have you looked into the outline css property? You can't really use it though if you have border-radiuses assigned... Because it wraps inside the element before the border radius is applied. try something like outline: 1px solid black; (This should only be applied to hover selectors)

Comment: That hover selector is for an `a` tag, not a `button`. The best thing to do at this point would be to put your code in a codepen or jsfiddle and test it in few browsers. If it's still happening, share it with us.

Comment: @Godwin the `a` selector is the correct one, the button is defined by `<a href="foo.html" class="button">bar</a>`